# Divs for rows in float based layout - when needed?

Tags: css, css-float

I want to layout my page with float based rows(fixed width), when each row has three divs (each 33% width).
Do I have to include each of the rows - in another "row" div (assume I warp with one div - all the rows)?

From what I understand, the "rows divs" are needed only if each "33% div" has different heights, or if I want some of the rows to include less then three "33% divs"...(for example - a row with two items and some empty area...).

In conclusion - If all my rows include three divs with 33% width, and all of them are the same height - then I don't need to add containing divs for the rows ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need divs for wrapping the row.

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is what you want

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        #container{
            position:relative;
        }

        .row{
            float: left;
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .row > div{
            width: 33%;
            float: left;
        }

        .row:nth-child(even){
            background-color: pink;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>foo</div>
            <div>bar<br/>big</div>
            <div>baz</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>foo</div>
            <div>bar<br/>another<br/>big<br/>one</div>
            <div>baz</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>foo</div>
            <div>shizzle<br/>for<br/>my<br/>nizzle</div>
            <div>baz</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

make sure to have a container with position:relative so width percentages are based on that container width.
and clear:both (or left only for that matter) on each new row.

if you're asking if you can leave the div.row out of it, you could, if you clear the first element of each row, but that will get you in trouble when using backgroundcolors on the cells themselves.

hope this helps

Comment: Yes I agree, you could leave the row unwrapped if you only have one row, but its dangerous and I would wrap it for 1) readability and 2) scalability.

Comment: you agree yet no approve? :p

Comment: heads up: i'm not a css expert, but this might fail in some browsers

Comment: Hey.1- If each cell is the same height - I think I don't need to use clear, the row will be formed automatically, if i'm not wrong. 2- what's the problem with background colors? (I'll still use a container for ALL rows...) Thanks.

Comment: 1) if each cell in same height in row, then i don't see a problem, but think of it as good practise to do so anyway. (at least that's my oppinion. 2) if they dont have the same height, and you use background colors on the cells and not the rows, the user will notice this.

Comment: if this answers your question, perhaps you could mark it as solution? if you'd be so kind :-D

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you used `inline-block` instead of float, for a couple of reasons:

1. If you are using a wrapping div for the 1/3rd width cells, then the wrapping div will be collapsed if you use floats.
2. If the cells have different heights (you mentioned they would be of same height, but just in case they aren't), then the floats will create a very bad sort of mish-mash alignment and the whole thing would just be a big disaster.

On the other hand, if you use this, things would be much cleaner and easier to extend. Also the wrapping div will not collapse:

```
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; // or top/bottom. depends on your taste :)
  width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: You can notice the "collapsed" divs using the floats when you put separate background colours for the row and cells.